# Eigen::Map unamed?

Tags: c++, c++11, c++14, c++17, eigen

Down here I tried to write random values to `a` using `Eigen` function:

```
double *a = (double*)malloc(N*N*sizeof(double));

Map<Matrix<double, N, N, RowMajor> >m(a);
m = MatrixXd::Random(N,N);
```

Is it possible to do the last part in just one line (without creating `m`)? I was imagining something like

```
Map<Matrix<double, N, N, RowMajor> >(a) = MatrixXd::Random(N,N);
```

But got

```
main.cpp:44:42: error: redefinition of 'a' with a different type: 'Map<Matrix<double, N, N, RowMajor> >' vs 'double *'
    Map<Matrix<double, N, N, RowMajor> >(a) = MatrixXd::Random(N,N);
                                         ^
main.cpp:42:13: note: previous definition is here
    double *a = (double*)malloc(N*N*sizeof(double));
            ^
1 error generated.
```

Comment: Just as the error message says - in the same scope you first declare `a` to be a `double*` and then in the next code line you declare it to be a `Map<whatever>`.  Perhaps at line 44 you wanted to declare `m` not `a` but did a copy/paste error?

Comment: In fact, intention is not to create `m`, instead, write directly to `a`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

C++ will ignore the `()` around `a` in a construct like

```
Type (a) = expr;
```

You can either write

```
( Type(a) ) = expr;
```

or with C++11:

```
Type{a} = expr;
```

For this case you can also use the static `Map` member function:

```
Matrix<double, N, N, RowMajor>::Map(a) = MatrixXd::Random(N,N);
```

or

```
Matrix<double, N, N, RowMajor>::Map(a).setRandom(); // size is specified by type
```